# ArcGIS - Make colour gradient in street network shapefile accordingly to buffer distance from central points (bus stops)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, buffer, road

I need to do a colour gradient in the street network shapefile (cyan selection in the map attached, in a layer) accordingly to the distance from the points in the other layer (the more distant, the darker), always inside the buffer.
[image: Multiple buffer]

In conclusion: I want to get this result (accessibility gradient from bus stops)
[image]

Comment: Any thoughts on what? I see you've taken the Tour, so you should narrow your question to be more specific, and hence more answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are only interesting in visualizing these colours and not worried about trying to encode the "distance" into the road network why not simply run the [Intersect Tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm)? Intersecting your road network with your polygon buffer layer. I'm assuming the buffer distance is a field in your buffer layer. By Intersecting these two layers you "chop" out the network to the limit of the buffers and the distance field is passed over to the new output polyline layer. Then you simply colour code by that field.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I intersected both layers and next coloured the "chopped" roads new layer via Simbology > Quantities > Graduated Colours > Fields value = distance (field from buffer layer). Thanks Hornbydd.